# C-; shows a strange popup with letter 'e'

Tags: key-bindings

I don't know when this problem began, may be 1 or 2 months ago.

When I press "C-;", Emacs shows a popup with letter "e".

[image: a popup with 'e' appears in Emacs window]

But this key binding is for "avy-goto-char-timer".

[image: M-x]

Even I run Emacs with `emacs --no-init-file`, this key binding still shows this popup.

I've searched but found nothing.

Emacs Version: GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.30, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-01-25, modified by Debian
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: My wild guess is that you're triggering the compose key in your desktop environment (GNOME).

Answer (score 3):

You’re using Gnome, and you’ve activated an IME. Emacs never registered your keypress, but it will accept any text supplied to it by the IME. You should examine the Gnome keyboard or keybindings settings to find out which keys are affected, and how to control them. Alternatively you could uninstall the `ibus` package using apt, but I don’t recommend that. IMEs can be very useful in many circumstances, and not just for Asian scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I've deleted the ibus shortcut, and everything back to normal. If any one want to know how to delete ibus shortcut follow this link [How to change ibus input method shortcut to Shift+Caps Lock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389776/how-to-change-ibus-input-method-shortcut-to-shiftcaps-lock)